# Trying to change banner image when hovering over navbar link

Tags: javascript, css, navbar

I'm trying to make an image at the top of my page change to another image when I'm hovering over a link in a list.  Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: <ul><li><a href="#foo">Link</a><div id="top" style="background-image: url ("image1"); position: absolute; top: 0;"</div></li></ul> - ul li a:hover div#top {background-image: url ("image2");}

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways. Here's a simple one:

```
<img id="topImg" scr="image.jpg" />

<a href="#" onmouseover="document.topImg.src='image_over.jpg'"
            onmouseout="document.topImg.src='image.jpg'">Rollover</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

if using jQuery:

```
$('#tabbar a').hover(
function(){$('#banner').attr('src',"newimg.png')}
function(){$('#banner').attr('src',"oldimg.png')}
)
```

if not:

call for onmouseover:

```
document.getElementById('banner').src = 'newimage.png'
```

call for onmouseout:

```
document.getElementById('banner').src = 'olgimage.png'
```

---

you can also use sprites and change the background position, so you have less resources and the image doesn't need to load while displaying

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS Sprite :
http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/

Just have a look on that...

It optimize the number of http request and it's quite easy to use...